# UIButton ImageView showing only a color fill

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton

I am setting a UIButton's ImageView.Image property to an image that was captured from an ImagePickerController.  In my app, the image is captured and rounded with a border.  The image is saved and I am loading the image into the button.  Problem is, the button is showing only a blue circle and not the image inside...  This only seems to happen on buttons.

Here is my code to round the image and set the border:

```
-(UIImage *)makeRoundedImage:(UIImage *) image
                  radius: (float) radius;
{
CALayer *imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
imageLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
imageLayer.contents = (id) image.CGImage;
imageLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];

imageLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
imageLayer.cornerRadius = radius;
imageLayer.borderWidth = 40;
UIColor *ios7BlueColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:122.0/255.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
imageLayer.borderColor = ios7BlueColor.CGColor;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
[imageLayer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return roundedImage;
}
```

And here is how I am setting the button image:(player.playerImage is a cordite string with the path to the saved image)

```
-(void)ViewController:(UIViewController *)sender didUpdatePlayerImage:(NSString *)playerImagePath
{

player.playerImage = playerImagePath;
[_editImageButton setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:player.playerImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Is this a limitation to the UIButton's ImageView implementation or am I missing something?

Comment: Please read the document called "Buttons" which is linked in the UIButton Class Reference. It will explain why you get the blue image and what to do about it.

Comment: Thanks.  This got me to the right place.  I had to set the UIRenderingMode to always original...

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually writing the original image into the context.

Try the following:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
[imageLayer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

That should render the image into the context, followed by your layer.

Comment: Hmm.  I am not seeing that.  And, when I read the image into a UIImageView from another view controller, it shows correctly.  The image seems to be saving properly, but the UIButton.ImageView is not rendering it properly...